# What is the difference between NTor and TAP?

Tags: security

Recently I read that Tor switched from TAP handshake requests to NTor handshake requests. This seems to improve the performance and doesn't put such a high load on relays ([because of Mevade](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/115/88)). However I couldn't find a description what TAP and NTor is. Could you provide an explanation and tell the difference between both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TAP is the original Tor Authentication Protocol, the one described in the [original Tor paper](http://freehaven.net/anonbib/#tor-design) ([html](http://freehaven.net/anonbib/cache/tor-design.html)).  A security proof was later done by [Goldberg at PET2006](http://freehaven.net/anonbib/#tap:pet2006) and I think this is where the name of the scheme and the TAP acronym comes from.

NTor is a new protocol that aims to use faster and stronger cryptographic primitives.  It is specified in [proposal 216](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/proposals/216-ntor-handshake.txt) and implemented in the [Tor 0.2.4.x branch](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/tor-0.2.4.8-alpha:/ChangeLog#l21).