# Hidden .onion service with 2048 bit (or 4096 bit) RSA private key -- how to host it?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services

2048 bit RSA is proven to be more secure than 1024 bit, so with the help of Scallion
I have generated a pair of hidden service hostname + 2048 bit private key for it
(there were 1024b 2048b and 4096b options, I decided to choose the middle)

Now, I am trying to launch the hidden service, but some unknown reasons Tor is giving lots of errors.
It looks like Tor is trying to interpret my 2048 bit RSA private key as 1024 bit RSA key, and as result fails

Do you know, how to enable "2048-bit private key mode" of Tor hidden service hosting? **If yes, how?**
And is it possible? (although I am sure it is, because I noticed there were debates about implementing 2048-bit RSA support at 2011 year, probably since much time have passed this feature is already there)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will almost certainly have to use a 1024 key. As of the current version to date, it doesn't seem as if 2048 or higher keys are supported.

> And is it possible? (although I am sure it is, because I noticed there were debates about
>   implementing 2048-bit RSA support at 2011 year, probably since much
>   time have passed this feature is already there)

Unfortunately, it likely isn't. The direction the developers seem to be leaning at this point is to use other methods of securing Tor network.

A couple of links:

https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2013-August/005259.html

[What is the difference between NTor and TAP?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/436/what-is-the-difference-between-ntor-and-tap)